# setting compass up for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ssas, compass-sass

I am running rails 2.3.9 and trying to run:

rake rails:template LOCATION=http://compass-style.org/rails/installer

to install compass into my existing project.

I am on a Windows vista machine and it's giving me:

rake aborted!
redirection forbidden: http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/raw/master/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/templates/compass-install-rails.rb -> https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/raw/master/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/templates/compass-install-rails.rb

So I tried to run:

$ rake rails:template LOCATION=https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/raw/master/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/templates/compass-install-rails.rb

but now I get:

```
applying  template: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/raw/master/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/templates/compass-install-rails.rb
```

rake aborted!
certificate verify failed

Answer (score 0):

you are running into an issue with github, not compass. Github recently switched to ssl and it has caused some problems with various libraries that use this kind of installation. you are using an https url as the clone url, which you probably don't have authentication for. try logging out of your github account, then going back to the compass repo home and copy the url as the public http url, or use the git protocol instead of http.

Comment: hi jed thanks for the reply but i am not logged into git hub please can you tell me the command i should be using ?   thanks alot

Comment: any reason you are not installing with these directions? http://compass-style.org/docs/